# Outlook and CSS : Strange behaviour

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a strange issue with outlook. A tool sends everyday an email with somes informations in a simple table.
Here is the HTML CODE used for this :

```
<style>p { font-family: Calibri; font-size: 15px; color: #002364 }</style>
<p>SOME TEXT</b></p>

<table style="width:600px;font-family: Calibri; font-size: 15px">
<tr><td style="background-color:#d2d8e4;color:#002364;width:200px">DESC1</td><td style="color:#002364">VAL1</td></tr>
<tr><td style="background-color:#d2d8e4;color:#002364;width:200px">DESC2</td><td style="color:#002364">VAL2</td></tr>
<tr><td style="background-color:#d2d8e4;color:#002364;width:200px">DESC3</td><td style="color:#002364">VAL3</td></tr>
<tr><td style="background-color:#d2d8e4;color:#002364;width:200px">DESC4</td><td style="color:#002364">VAL4</td></tr>
</table>
```

In a browser (IE,Chrome,Firefox), everything is fine.

But in outlook...I don't know why but the CSS doesn't seem to be taken in account in the first TD of the first TR (and only here ! It's OK everywhere else).
I mean the text "DESC1" - for some strange reason - is not displayed in font Calibri (but in the default font used in outlook, Times I guess) whereas it is mentionned in the table style AND the color of the text is black whereas it is mentionned in the td style that color is #002364 (some dark blue).
Other strange thing is that background color is OK (color #d2d8e4 as mentionned).

This is really weird.
Other thing, in my code, I tried to switch lines...just to verify. For example, I put line with "DESC2" and "VAL2" above linde with "DESC1" and "VAL2". When I do that, it's "DESC2" which become black with Times font.

So outlook really doesn't like the first TD of the first TR it sees...What's wrong ???

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity debugging wise; did you trying cloning the td in question and setting it to display none or hidden? Just to see what will happen then. Also did you look at source code of the email too see how its presented there?

Comment: Hello. With a display none, "DESC1" doesn't appear in my TD. And I posted here the email source code :)